# jQuery if url first segment contains

Tags: jquery

if url contains like this and I want to if segment1 equals something then do this...

```
http://stackoverflow.com/segment1/segment2
```

like:

```
if (segment1 = 'anyword')
{
 ..then do this
}
```

something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split up the url:

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/segment1/segment2";

var splits = url.replace('http://', '').split('/');

if(splits[1] == "segment1"){

}
```

Comment: is there a difference between this and ur prev code? var splits = url.split('/');if(splits[3] == "segment1"){}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
var myurl = "http://stackoverflow.com/segment1/segment2";

if(myurl.split('/')[3] == "segment1")
{
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s1 = "foo";
alert(s1.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

OR

```
if (/anyword/.test(self.location.href))
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the url, and check each pathname etc. but if you're only trying to check if the url contains something you could just do:

```
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/segment1/segment2';

if (url.indexOf('segment1') != -1) {
   //do this
}
```